# PHP ob_start(): how to get html from PHP page with URL parameters

Tags: php, html

I have a php page and it is called with parameters in the URL:

```
./mypage.php?id=12
```

I would need to render as pdf and I'm using dompdf, but before I have to convert the php page to html:

```
ob_start();
require './mypage.php?id=12'; 
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

but this way get me the error:

***require(./mypage.php?id=12): failed to open stream***

if I don't put the parameter (then simply `require './mypage.php'`) the pdf starts creating but then fails since the variable "id" is missing...

is there a way to specify those parameters?

thanks

Comment: You cannot pass parameters to a script using `include` or `require`

Comment: To get the _output_ of the page into a variable, you'd need to use file_get_contents with a URL. But that's a silly way to do it when it's on your own server... instead, separate off the code which creates the relevant output into a function you can call from more than one place.

Comment: `$_REQUEST['id'] = '12';` or `$_GET['id'] = '12';`, whichever your page uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add get parameters to an include, since it is not a get request.
Instead, use:

```php
ob_start();
$id = $_GET['id'];
require './mypage.php'; 
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

And in `mypage.php`:

```php
//... use $id in your code
```

Comment: awesome, I did it! thanks to all for your suggestions!!!! EXCELLENT!!! many many thanks!

Comment: no sorry, it works perfectly on chrome, but on firefox it has a weird behaviour. It doesn't recognize the output to the brwoser (preview) but it asks to open/save the output... no problems also with opera or edge. only firefox (my version is 94.0.1)

Comment: Your question was about how to pass a variable to a require/include. Maybe you can start another question for your error in firefox.